# Proving that Euclidean space having the infinity metric is a complete metric space (stuck)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to prove that the space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ with the $\infty$-metric is a complete metric space.

I know that I need to show that every Cauchy sequence in the metric space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ with the $\infty$-metric converges to a point $x\in{\mathbb{R}}^k$. Part of my work so far involved proving that the space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ with the old Pythagorean norm is a complete metric space, but I’m not sure if I should be using that at all in this proof. Here goes:

Proof:

Suppose that $k\in{\mathbb{N}}$ and that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ with the $\infty$-metric. 
Suppose that $\epsilon>0$. 
Using the fact that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence, choose an integer $N$ such that the inequality $||x_{m}-x_{n}||_\infty<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ holds for all integers $m$ and $n$ such that $m\ge{N}$ and $n\ge{N}$.

This is where I’m stuck. I feel like I want to use the triangle inequality from here…

Since the space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ is a metric space, we know that the inequality $$||{x_n}-{x_m}||_{\infty}\le||{x_n}-{x}||_{\infty}+||{x_m}-{x}||_{\infty}\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$ holds for all positive integers $n$ and $m$.

However, I know that this isn’t a good thing to state. I think that I’m assuming that there is some point $x$ in the space that the sequence converges to… this is exactly what I'm trying to prove! 
I’m totally stuck. Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated!

EDIT: I'm including the updated version of my proof based on advice from Brian M. Scott. Here it is:

Proof:

Suppose that $k\in{\mathbb{N}}$ and that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence in the space ${\mathbb{R}}^k$ with the $\infty$-metric.

Suppose that $\epsilon>0$.

For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ we have $x_{n}= \left(x_{n,1},x_{n,2},\ldots,x_{n,k}\right)$.

Consider the real-valued sequences $\left(x_{n,j}\right)$ for each $j=1,2,\ldots,k$.

Using the fact that $\left(x_{n}\right)$ is a Cauchy sequence, choose $N\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that the inequality $||x_{m} – x_{n}||_{\infty}\lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $n\ge N$ and $m\ge N$.

Since the inequality $||x_{m,j} – x_{n,j}||_{\infty}\le||x_{m} – x_{n}||_{\infty}$ holds for all $m$ and $n$, we have the inequality $||x_{m,j} – x_{n,j}||_{\infty}\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $m\ge N$ and $n\ge N$.

Thus for $j=1,2,\ldots,k$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ the sequence $\left( x_{n,j} \right)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Using the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, define $$x\left(j\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n,j}$$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,k$.

The point $x=\left(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{k}\right)$ is the limit of $\left(x_{n}\right)$ under the Pythagorean metric.

From the inequality $$||x-x_{n}||_\infty\le||x-x_{m}||_{\infty}+||x_{m}-x_{n}||_{\infty}\lt\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$ that holds for all $n\ge N$ and $m\ge N$ we see that the sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges to the point $x\in\mathbb{R}^{k}$ and the space $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ is a complete metric space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: There are at least two reasonable approaches.

1. Start with a Cauchy sequence $\langle x^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where $x^n=\langle x_1^n,\dots,x_k^n\rangle$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Now look at the real-valued sequences $\langle x_i^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ for $i=1,\dots,k$. Show that each is Cauchy in the usual metric on $\Bbb R$, let $x_i$ be the limit (since $\Bbb R$ is complete in the usual metric), and show that $\langle x^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $\langle x_1,\dots,x_k\rangle$ in $\Bbb R^k$.
2. Show that the $\infty$ metric is equivalent to the Euclidean metric. Then a sequence is Cauchy in one of these metrics if and only if it’s Cauchy in the other, it converges to a point $x$ in one if and only if it converges to $x$ in the other, and you already know that the Euclidean metric is complete.

Comment: In your second approach, what do you mean by "equivalent"? I thought they were different types of distance measure? I know that $||x||_{\infty}\le{||x||}$, but I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: You’re welcome. I mean [this notion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Strong_equivalence) of strong equivalence: there are positive constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that for all $x,y\in\Bbb R^k$, $\alpha\|x-y\|\le\|x-y\|_\infty\le\beta\|x-y\|$. (You may prefer the first approach: it’s much closer to what you had in mind initially.)

Comment: For the first approach, when you talk about the real-valued sequences $\langle x_i^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ for $i=1,...,k$ are you basically saying focus on each axis individually? It seems like you're saying establish the fact that the coordinates on each axis will converge to a value in $\mathbb{R}$, and each limit on each axis will be the respective coordinate of the actual limit point. Am I interpreting that correctly? 

If so, how would I factor the $\infty$ metric into all of this?

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: Yes, you’re interpreting it correctly. The $\infty$ metric is probably the *easiest* one with which to use this argument: for each coordinate $i$, $|x_i^m-x_i^n|\le\|x^m-x^n\|_\infty$ for all $m,n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: $Brian M. Scott: I've revised my proof based on what you said, but I still feel like I'm not quite there. Will you let me know if I'm moving in the right direction? Please and thank you!

By the way, the new proof is too long for this comment box, so I'm going to add it as an edit to the original post. Thanks again!

Comment: I apologize for being dense about this stuff, I'm still really new to real analysis. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: I’m sorry; I got called away and forgot about this. A few points. (1) $\|x_{m,j}-x_{n,j}\|_\infty$ looks a bit weird: it’s just $|x_{m,j}-x_{n,j}|$ and would be clearer so written. (2) There’s no reason to use $\frac{\epsilon}2$: $\epsilon$ is fine. (3) You’re working too hard to show that the original sequence converges to $x$. You know that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_{n,j}-x_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$ and all $j$, so $$\|x_n-x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_{n,j}-x_j|:j=1,\dots,k\}<\epsilon$$ for all $n\ge m_\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting the inequality $|x_{n,j}-x_{n}|\lt\epsilon$. I know it says "the absolute value of the difference between the $jth$ coordinate of the $nth$ point and the norm of the $nth$ point itself is less than $\epsilon$", but I don't know what this means geometrically. Is this the length along the $jth$ axis of the $nth$ point minus the length from the origin to the $nth$ point itself? How do we know that this difference is less than $\epsilon$? Thanks again for your reply! And no worries, about forgetting, I just get anxious.

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: Oops! That should have been $|x_{n,j}-x_j|$; it’s just the distance between the projections to the $j$-th axis of $x_n$ and $x$.

Comment: Ah, so is my citing the triangle inequality the part on which I'm working too hard? Should I just say something like: $|x_{n,j}-x_{j}|\le|x_{n}-x|\lt\epsilon$ for each $n\geN$ and each $j=1,2,\ldots,k$ and so the sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ converges to the point $x$?

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: No, you have that backwards. You first use the convergence of each $\langle x_{n,j}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ to $x_j$ to say that if $\epsilon>0$, there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that for each $j=1,\dots,k$, $|x_{n,j}-x_j|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. This implies that if $n\ge m_\epsilon$, then $$\|x_n-x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_{n,j}-x_j|:j=1,\dots,k\}<\epsilon\;,$$ and since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, this in turn implies that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to x$.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a point at which all this "clicks" and makes sense? I work through the exercises and do the reading required by my professor, but it still doesn't feel like it hits home. I get what it means for a sequence to be eventually in a ball, which gives us limits, but this completeness is tough for me.

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: A Cauchy sequence is a sequence that ‘ought’ to converge: go far enough out in the sequence, and you can make the tail arbitrarily small. You can prove without too much trouble that such a sequence can have at most one limit point. However, in some metric spaces they don’t all converge. In $\Bbb Q$, for instance, with the usual metric, the sequence $$\langle 1,1.4,1.41,1.414,1.4142,1.41421,\dots\rangle$$ is a Cauchy sequence that doesn’t converge to any point of the space $\Bbb Q$. (In $\Bbb R$, of course, it converges to $\sqrt2$.) The metric space is complete ...

Comment: ... if all of these sequences that ought to converge actually do: in a sense there aren’t any ‘holes’ in the space in the way that the irrationality of $\sqrt2$ makes a ‘hole’ in $\Bbb Q$. It turns out that there’s a procedure for taking a non-complete metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ and ‘filling in the holes’ to embed it in a bigger metric space $\langle\tilde X,\tilde d\rangle$, called its *completion*; $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric is the completion of $\Bbb Q$ with the usual metric. And that’s really most of the intuition involved right there; just about everything else is technique.

Comment: Nice, thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Euclid'sCompass: You’re welcome; I hope that it helps at least a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Since $$\max_{1\leq i\leq d}|x_i|^2\leq\sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|^2\leq d\ \max_{1\leq i\leq d}|x_i|^2$$ one has
$$\|{\bf x}\|_\infty\leq\|{\bf x}\|_2\leq\sqrt{d}\>\|{\bf x}\|_\infty\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R}^d)\ .$$
Therefore the identity map
$${\rm id}:\quad\bigl({\mathbb R}^d,\ \|\cdot\|_\infty\bigr)\ \to\ \bigl({\mathbb R}^d, \ \|\cdot\|_2\bigr)$$
is Lipschitz in both directions. This means that distances between points measured one way or the other differ by a factor at most $\sqrt{d}$. It follows that a sequence $({\bf x}_n)_{n\geq0}$ in ${\mathbb R}^d$ is Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ iff it is Cauchy with respect to $\|\cdot\|_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This looks much simpler and quicker than the approach that I am trying to take, but I'm not sure what identity maps are, or what it means for one to be Lipschitz. I'm sure it'll make sense eventually though! Thanks again.